# python - openchange provision failure

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, provisioning

Ubuntu 12.04.5
When I get to the part where I need to provision openchange detailed here: http://www.openchange.org/cookbook/configuring.html

I am directed to type in the following command:

```
:~/openchange# sudo PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH ./setup/openchange_provision --standalone
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
NOTE: This operation can take several minutes
[+] Step 1: Register Exchange OIDs
[+] Step 2: Add Exchange attributes to Samba schema
schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request

Error: "(53, 'schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request\n')" when adding element:

 ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
 Contains the mapping for the access controls.

dn: CN=ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=stremblay,DC=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: attributeSchema
cn: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
distinguishedName: CN=ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=stremblay,DC=local
attributeID: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.7000.102.64
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
isSingleValued: TRUE
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE
adminDisplayName: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
adminDescription: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
oMSyntax: 64
searchFlags: 0
lDAPDisplayName: msExchAccessControlMap
name: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
 schemaIDGUID: 8ff54464-b093-11d2-aa06-00c04f8eedd8
isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet: FALSE
objectCategory: CN=Attribute-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=stremblay,DC=local

[!] error while provisioning the Exchange schema classes (53): schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup/openchange_provision", line 109, in <module>
    openchange.provision(setup_path, provisionnames, lp, creds)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openchange/provision.py", line 777, in provision
    install_schemas(setup_path, names, lp, creds, reporter)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openchange/provision.py", line 447, in install_schemas
    provision_schema(sam_db, setup_path, names, reporter, schema['path'], schema['description'], schema['modify_mode'])
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openchange/provision.py", line 233, in provision_schema
    sam_db.add_ldif(el, ['relax:0'])
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/__init__.py", line 224, in add_ldif
    self.add(msg, controls)
_ldb.LdbError: (53, 'schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request\n')
root@mail:~/openchange# error while provisioning the Exchange schema classes (53): schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request
```

Any help to solve this error

Comment: solved Add this in your smb.conf:

Comment: dsdb:schema update allowed=true

Comment: you can answer your own question. This helped me so I recommend you doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your smb.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

# [global] 
dsdb:schema update allowed=true
```